# how to create a javascript random quiz based on user data that is generated from a model (ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, random, model

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and Javascript. I'd like to use Javascript to create a random quiz that does the following:

1) collects all data from user-generated posts in 3 different models (e.g. Articles, Countries, Insights) and all of their subfields (e.g. article.title, article.categorytype, country.name, country.capital, country.population, etc)

2) creates 10 random questions based on all the data gathered in part 1. For example, "What is the categorytype of"+article.title[2]+"?" The quiz taker would see the title of the randomly selected article, and would have 4 choices to select from, one of which will be the correct categorytype that corresponds to the articletitle, and the other 3 will be randomly selected categorytypes that belong to other articles.

Another random question could be, (randomcapital)+"is the capital of which country?" and be presented with 4 choices, one of which is the corresponding country and the others 3 random other countries from the countries list.

3) Once the user selects their answer to all ten random questions, and presses "Submit", they would get their score of how many questions they got right, until they get all ten right. Once they get all ten right, the page would be reloaded with a new quiz with new random questions.

---

I've already begun doing part 1 with the following code on my quiz.html.erb file, where articles is a model that belongs_to quiz, which is another model that has_many articles:

```
<% x=0 %>

<% article_title = [] %>
<% article_categorytype = [] %>

<% @quiz.articles.each do |article| %>
 <% article_title[x] = article.title %>
 <% article_categorytype[x] = article.categorytype %>
  <% x+=1 %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: I know my code above is not javascript, so I also need to figure out how to translate it into javascript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Use Cookies, To track what people are interested in, then have a array of things linking to that particular subject, then use JSON To stpre random questions etc...

```
var json = {"Questions"["Question" : "What are you called?" , "Question" : "hello?"]}
```

then i would have a for loop example:

```
for(var i = 0;i < yourArray.length; i++){
question=[json.Questions.Question];
document.write('Your html' + question[i]);
}
```

This is basic though you would obviously need better algorithms

Comment: Thanks John. Do you know how to pull model data into Javascript?

Comment: Use the Ruby on Rails to echo in data

Comment: For those looking for help in the future, see this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast. You can use `data` attributes or JS tags in the views to pass in the data.